# Regular expression - substitute

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a bit of a perl noob and trying to work out how to strip some zeros out of a piece of text.
The line looks something like this:

```
76.000 to 80.000
```

and I'm trying to remove the zeros to make it look like this

```
76.0 to 80.0
```

but can't for the life of me get the regex work.

This is what I have,

```
if ($data =~ m/00/) # This is working

{

   $data = s/(.*)\00(\s\[to]\s)(.*)\00/($1)($3)($4)/; # This isn't

}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply this:

```
$data =~ s/0+$/0/;
```

Comment: Thanks WoLpH. This works. It looks like I might have confused myself by leaving the "~" out. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic way of truncating floating point numbers inside strings:

```
s/([\d.]+)/ sprintf '%.1f', $1 /ge
```

Using a `sprintf` inside a substitution to format whatever is captured, by using evaluation. Note that this will coerce all numbers to this format.

A more specific way to handle the problem would be

```
s/\d+\.0\K0*//g
```

Using the `\K` (keep) escape to preserve digits followed by period and a zero, and removing all subsequent zeroes after that string.